# Mod Rewrite Regex Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-greedy, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match all URIs that begin with `#/tool_[a-z\-]+#` *except* if it's followed by `/public`.  Such as `/tool_calculator` or whatever.

For example, if the URI begins with `/tool_store-front` or `/tool_store-front/anything-but-public` then I want to redirect them to HTTPS.  So, `/tool_store-front/public` would *not* redirect.

Here's what I have and it's not working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?tool_[a-z-]+(?!/public.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?secure
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?secure/public/info
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also change your negative lookahead condition to this using a **possessive quantifier**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tool_[a-z-]++(?!/public) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/secure(?!/public/info) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

You can also use this negative lookahead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tool_[a-z-]+(?!.*/public) [NC,OR]
```

**Problem** in your condition `^/?tool_[a-z-]+(?!/public.+)` is that regex engine is backtracking `[a-z]+`, one position before `/` to assert negative lookahead `(?!/public.+)` true.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks <3.  But how is it that it's backtracking `[a-z]+` as you said?  I didn't quite follow :'(

Comment: [See this demo to understand better](https://regex101.com/r/Zipw5q/1) Check `regex debugger` link to understand backtracking part better. Once that is clear change regex to `^/tool_[a-z-]++(?!/public)` and now there will be no match and again check `regex debugger`